# Javascript: Change internal variable with external function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am trying to run a function to cancel common factors between two numbers.  The cancelling function is outside of my wrapper function "multiplyFraction" and it won't change the variables inside of multiplyFraction.

```
function cancelFac(num1,num2){
    var minVal = Math.min(num1,num2); 
    for(var i=2; i<=minVal; i++){ 
        while(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0){ 
            num1 = num1/i;
            num2 = num2/i;
        }
    }
}


var multiplyFraction = function(){      
    var a = notZero(rand(13,0)); 
    var b = notZero(rand(13,0));

    //Cancel Common factors
    cancelFac(a,b);
}
```

The values of a and b remain unchanged. When I put the for loop directly inside of multiplyFraction it works great, but I wanted to make cancelling factors it's own function because I need to do it so often.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of a and b will remain unchanged because they are primitive types and primitive types are passed by value than reference. If you want to maintain the changes done to vlaues being passed then pass the values by reference i.e pass the object instead of primitive types. Or return an object from `cancelFac` method. Try this.

```
function cancelFac(num1,num2){
    var minVal = Math.min(num1,num2); 
    for(var i=2; i<=minVal; i++){ 
        while(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0){ 
            num1 = num1/i;
            num2 = num2/i;
        }
    }

 return { num1: num1, num2: num2 };
}

var multiplyFraction = function(){      
  var obj = {
    a: notZero(rand(13,0)),
    b: notZero(rand(13,0))
  };

  //Cancel Common factors
  obj = cancelFac(obj.a, obj.b);
}
```

Comment: sorry it took more than 1 year to accept this,  I was just looking over my old questions and noticed I had not done that yet

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the return function in cancelFac to return you a string in this format "num1,num2" . Now in the multiplyFraction method , split the string and get the values of a and b.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can also return an array containing num1 and num2 :

```
function cancelFac(num1,num2){
    var minVal = Math.min(num1,num2); 
    for(var i=2; i<=minVal; i++){ 
        while(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0){ 
            num1 = num1/i;
            num2 = num2/i;
        }
    }
    return [num1, num2];
}

var multiplyFraction = function(){      
    var a = notZero(rand(13,0)); 
    var b = notZero(rand(13,0));

    //Cancel Common factors
    var result  = cancelFac(a,b);
    a = result[0];
    b = result[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the return value to return the changed values in an object (or an array):

```
function cancelFac(num1,num2){
    var minVal = Math.min(num1,num2); 
    for(var i=2; i<=minVal; i++){ 
        while(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0){ 
            num1 = num1/i;
            num2 = num2/i;
        }
    }
    return({a: num1, b: num2});
}

var multiplyFraction = function(){      
var a = notZero(rand(13,0)); 
var b = notZero(rand(13,0));

//Cancel Common factors
var result = cancelFac(a,b);
a = result.a;
b = result.b;
```

Or, you could pass in an object and have it change the values in place in that object if you wanted to:

```
function cancelFac(in){
    var num1 = in.num1, num2 = in.num2;
    var minVal = Math.min(num1,num2); 
    for(var i=2; i<=minVal; i++){ 
        while(num1%i==0 && num2%i==0){ 
            num1 = num1/i;
            num2 = num2/i;
        }
    }
    // set results back into passed in object
    in.num1 = num1;
    in.num2 = num2;
}

var multiplyFraction = function(){      
var data = {num1: notZero(rand(13,0), num2: notZero(rand(13,0)};

//Cancel Common factors
cancelFac(data);
// data.num1 and data.num2 contain the two modified values
```